# Recursion and Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, recursion

In the following code I am trying to get the contents of an xml tag if it is found in a tree, using recursion. Issue is that the tag is found but every call to self starts up a new thread and hence in the end return value is NOT_FOUND whereas it should have stopped before when found. Challenge is to set the exit condition any help pointers will be appreciated..

```
// Recursive method to find a XmlElement value
- (NSString*) valueOf : (XMLElement*) elementIn :(NSString*) tag
{
    NSString *retValue = @"NOT_FOUND";

    if ([self tagMatch:elementIn :tag]){
        retValue = elementIn.text;
        found = 1;
    } else {
        for (XMLElement *anElement in elementIn.subElements)
        {
            [self valueOf:anElement :tag];
        }
    }
    return retValue;
}

- (int) tagMatch : (XMLElement*) elementIn :(NSString*) tag
{
    int found = 0;

    if([elementIn.name isEqualToString:tag]) {
        NSLog (@"Found tag %@, value = %@", tag, elementIn.text);
        found = 1;
    }
    return found;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any code that starts a new thread?

Comment: I know, but when I debug using Xcode, I can see new threads created in the debug window. Sorry I am new to Xcode and objc.

Comment: Well there are no new threads being created in the code you posted, so those threads must be created elsewhere.  So what is the issue with this code?

Comment: in the calling method this call returns NOT_FOUND.NSString *tagValue = [self valueOf: self.rootElement : @"CelsiusToFahrenheitResult"];
        NSLog (@"CelsiusToFahrenheitResult = %@", tagValue);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your while loop

```
retValue = [self valueOf:anElement :tag];
if(![retValue isEqualToString:@"NOT_FOUND"]){
    break;
}
```

You're not using the return value from the inner method calls.

Comment: Boy that was quick, Thanks alex-i, got it! Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably easier to use the value of `nil` to signal *not found*, as that's easier to test.  You can always change the value to `@"Not Found"` during *presentation* (i.e. when you add the string to a UI element):

```
- (NSString *)valueOf:(XMLElement*)elementIn:(NSString*)tag
{
    NSString *retValue = nil;

    if ([self tagMatch:elementIn:tag]) {
        retValue = elementIn.text;
    } else {
        for (XMLElement *anElement in elementIn.subElements) {
            if (retValue = [self valueOf:elementIn:tag])
                break;
        }
    }
    return retValue;
}
```